# Segmentation fault in program loaded with custom binfmt handler; same program in ELF format runs seamlessly

Tags: assembly, process, linux-kernel, segmentation-fault, portable-executable

I've been working on a custom PE `binfmt` handler for Ubuntu Linux 12.04, Intel x86_64 architecture (if this sounds familiar, I've posted a few questions related to this project already). I'll apologize in advance if the amount of information I'm giving is overkill.

The `binfmt` handler is pretty standard; I read in the PE headers and sections and then write those sections into userspace memory at the addresses specified in the section table. Then, when everything is ready, I call

```
start_thread(regs, entry_addr, current->mm->start_stack);
```

exactly like the built-in Linux handlers do; in my case, `regs = 0xcf7dffb4`, `entry_addr = 0x401000`, and `start_stack = 0xbffff59b`.

I have the following code, in Intel x86 assembly:

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp

mov eax, 4
add eax, 5

pop ebp
ret
```

I compile this program with [fasm](http://flatassembler.net) to a PE format executable (math1.exe) and install my `binfmt` handler with `insmod`. If I debug this program in `gdb`, I see:

```
(gdb) set disassembly-flavor intel
(gdb) x/6i 0x401000
    0x401000:   push   ebp
    0x401001:   mov    ebp,esp
    0x401003:   mov    eax,0x4
    0x401008:   add    eax,0x5
    0x40100b:   pop    ebp
    0x40100c:   ret
```

so I know the code is loaded to the correct address. Then:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /media/sf_Sandbox/math1.exe 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0040100c in ?? ()
```

When I do a register dump:

```
(gdb) info registers
eax            0x9  9
ecx            0x81394e8    135501032
edx            0x8137808    135493640
ebx            0x8139548    135501128
esp            0xbfffe59b   0xbfffe59b
ebp            0x0  0x0
esi            0x81394e8    135501032
edi            0x2f7ff4 3112948
eip            0x40100c 0x40100c
...other registers...
```

You can see that the code did execute because `eax = 0x9`, as it should. On the surface, I can't find any reason for this to segfault at the `ret` statement, though. Examining `dmesg`, I found

```
math1.exe[1864] general protection ip:40100c sp:bffff5bd error:0
```

but I've found very little documentation on what might be causing this. I know the problem isn't the code itself, because the same code compiled with the same assembler to ELF format runs with no trouble whatsoever.

My current theories about this problem are:

1. I don't really mess with the stack pointer in my handler. The built-in Linux handlers (for ELF, a.out, and flat formats, to name three) have a function `create_*_tables()` that processes the `argc`, `argv`, and `envp` arguments. I didn't include this function at first because the test program doesn't take any input, but implementing the `create_flat_tables()` function (from the flat handler) doesn't solve the problem so far. (I know that blindly pasting and calling functions from other modules is a **bad** idea, but the a.out and flat versions of that function are essentially identical, so it doesn't seem to be very dependent on the executable format; I thought I'd give it a try.)
2. I found [this article](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html) about the chain of function calls that occurs prior to and following the execution of `main()`. The `objdump` of math1.exe contains only the assembly code given above, but the `objdump` of the same program after assembly to ELF format (which yields a `*.o` file) and linking with `gcc` (to get an ELF binary) contains the other functions mentioned in the article (`_start()`, `__libc_start_main()`, etc.). Perhaps those functions are more mandatory on the Linux platform than I previously thought.

I'm looking for any explanations/suggestions/further troubleshooting steps I could take. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's quite odd that your `esp` is um... odd. Do you initialize it at all? If you add a subroutine to your code (as simple as `ret`) and `call` it, will those two `call/ret` instructions execute or will you get an exception at `call`?

Comment: You need to call exit(), as the answer below says. I suspect you're SEGV'ing because the `ret` is going off into la-la-land.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need to implement at least one aspect of the `_start` and `__libc_start_main` sequence: calling the _exit syscall. You can't just execute a "ret" from the frame that was created by execve and expect that to cause the process to terminate cleanly. Returning from main to exit the process is a C feature, and your program isn't C.

My memory is a little fuzzy on the syscall interface but I believe it goes like this:

1. set %eax to the syscall number (`_NR_exit`)
2. set %ebx to the first argument (the exit code)
3. int $0x80

additional args to %ecx, %edx, ... I'm not sure of the order. But _exit() only takes one arg and I'm pretty sure it goes in %ebx.